# Drupal set related nodes while creating new node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Is there any module which list the related nodes based on the title and body at the time of creating new node, So that the user can set multiple related node.

And there is a block on the node page which list the set of selected related links

Any Help,

Thanks,
Edvin :)

Comment: Questions about module usage and selection are best placed on  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the drupal module and did some customization,

Here you go sure it will help you guys,
[Node Recommendation](http://drupal.org/project/noderecommendation)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7

Answer (score 0):

**Most direct answer to your question:**

What you are asking, in order to do this task *well*, requires very smart, semantically-aware programming - i.e., a LOT of complicated code.  There is the [Similar Entries Module](http://drupal.org/project/similar) - I haven't tried this, so don't know how good a job it does.  Very likely, it will only match similar words, and articles with words that simple programming identifies as similar are not always actually about similar content.  So: it will work, but it won't be matching very "intelligently."

*However, you could also consider:*

**1.** There are available module-integrated webservices, such as [Calais](http://drupal.org/project/opencalais), which can help you show *other sites'* content that's related - but not your own - and do the semantic comparison in a sophisticated and language-aware manner.

**2.**  Probably the best way to assure that articles which are similar in content is to classify what your articles are about yourself by using a taxonomy vocabulary.  You could then make sure that the taxonomy term is put in the url with [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto), and use this part of the url as an argument in Views to select articles with the same taxonomy term.  This view could then be displayed as a block, or embedded somewhere in your article template.

**3.**  If you get really picky and decide that for each article you want to manually decide which other articles it's related to - you could add a multiple-set of CCK node reference fields to your article node, and simply display these.

Comment: Hmm the main concept is when the user create a new node, He have to select the related nodes[list of nodes(based on words of the current title & body) with check boxes ]. Once user submitted, the related issue will be listed in a block on that particular node view page

Comment: can you tell me about "add a multiple-set of CCK node reference fields to your article node" how to configure this in detail plz.

Comment: The Node Reference module needs to be activated (you'll find it on your modules admin page in the family of CCK-related modules).  Then on your content type, go to "manage fields" and add a new field - make it of the type "node reference" - the node reference can either reference all content type articles or, if you need it to be more specific, you can create a view which "filters" out which ones can potentially be displayed as similar entries - http://drupal.org/node/289738.  Note: this will just be a text box that your user has got to type words in to find article names.

Comment: I think however, given your first comment - it sounds like the users that are submitting this content can't be relied on to know the names of titles of content that's similar.  So you may well be better off with the Similar Entries Module.